# Can't find 'ClassLibrary' in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The version of Visual studio 2010 that I'm using is 10.0.30319.1 TRMRel . It's really strange when I want to add a new project, I can see just some of project types (not all of them like classlibrary)!!! I have looked for ClassLibrary every where ,but no luck.
I have tried to reset my settings by "Import and Export Setting" / Reset all setting and choose 'Visual C# Development setting' . but still nothing changes !

I appreciate any help

Thank you,

Comment: I also suggest posting an image of what you CAN see, like Pavithra did in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think what you need is this,go to

file -> add -> new project -> then select your language -> class library

use the link for the image for further clarification..

http://lh3.ggpht.com/_cUEAdZN-NYo/TQmdR5OGYsI/AAAAAAAAASQ/Yy2Wdlhl3VA/s720/vs.png